# PHP method argument typehint of class object - can an class inheriting from defined in type proceed?

Tags: php, inheritance, methods, type-hinting

If I have class Page and SubPage. SubPage inherits from Page. Then I have another class and its method where the method has defined argument type as object class of Page. If I call the method with instance of Page class everything should be fine. But if I call this method with SubPage instead of the Page class instance as defined, what will be the result? Will it proceed or will it drop exception?

**Called class and its method:**

```
Class ABC {
public function testMethod(Page $pageInstanceObject){}
}

class Page{
}
class SubPage extends Page{
}
```

**Page and SubPage calls:**

```
$ABC = new ABC();

$page = new Page();
$ABC->testMethod($page);

$subpage = new SubPage();
$ABC->testMethod($subpage);
```

Comment: Does `SubPage` extend `Page` ?

Comment: Just run the code instead of asking and you'll have your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the class inheriting can proceed from type hint if the class actually extends - inherits from the class defined in the type hint.